# Append HTML to iframe

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add a HTML element to an iframe, but each time I inspect the source code, nothing has been added.

My code is below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <iframe class="canvas" #canvas></iframe>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.scss'],
})
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addHtml();
  }

  addHtml(): void {
    const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement.contentDocument;
    canvas.appendChild('<h1>TEST CONTENT</h1>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another hook: `ngAfterViewInit`

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef<HTMLFrameElement>;
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.addHtml();
  }

  addHtml(): void {
    const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body;
    const el = document.createElement('h1');
    el.innerHTML = `Hello world`;

    canvas.appendChild(el);
  }
}

export default CanvasComponent;
```

You also can use

```
@ViewChild('canvas', {static: true}) canvas: ElementRef<HTMLFrameElement>;
```

And access it with

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.addHtml();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I get the `contentWindow` is deprecated error. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: According to the lib.dom.d.ts all properties of the HTMLFrameElement are deprecated.  However, MDN has no warnings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow 
So I don't have an answer.